# access a public function in .ascx

Tags: asp.net

how can i access a public function in an .ascx file using C#?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the function is not static you will need to first obtain an instance of the class containing the function and then invoke the function on this instance. For example:

```
<%
    // obtain an instance of the type containing the function
    Foo instance = new Foo();
    // invoke the function on this instance
    string result = instance.Bar();
%>
```

Obviously it would be better to do this in the code behind file instead of polluting your markup.

Answer (score 2):

Like other public functions in .NET Framework - via object reference. But sometimes Visual Studio doesn't automatically see your User Control's public members. Try to rebuild your user control and the site if IntelliSense window doesn't show it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling the function from? The containing page? Masterpage? Parent control? The control itself? Regardless, you'll need to somehow obtain a reference to the control instance (unless the method is static) in order to invoke this method. And the type of your reference must match that of the class that defines the method.

Edit:

```
MyControl myControl = (MyControl)Page.FindControl("Id_Of_The_Control"); 
if (myControl != null) 
{ 
    myControl.TheMethod(); 
}
```

Comment: im trying to call it from an .aspx file

Comment: Is the UserControl just on the page or is it inside a templated control like a DataGrid or a Wizard or something? If it's just on the page then you can use FindControl. See my updated answer.

Comment: Not sure if by "from an .aspx file" you mean in the code behind or somehow in the markup? You can access public properties in the markup, i.e. <cc:MyControl ... MyProperty="Wow" />. But I'm pretty sure you can't do that with a method, not sure why you'd want to.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to add your ascx control into a placeholder programmatically, just implement `IAttributeAccessor` and `IUserControlDesignerAccessor` interfaces to your user control class like;

```
public partial class yourascxclassname: System.Web.UI.UserControl, IAttributeAccessor,  IUserControlDesignerAccessor
```

you can access only public members of your ascx control.